# iOS - Amazon s3 client using temporary credentials

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tvm

I am developing an iOS application, in which I am using amazon S3 token vending machine to upload media files

I managed to get the temporary credentials (the access ID, the access key, and the session token)

How should I use them to create an AmazonS3Client and start an upload request?

Answer (score 0):

They have [examples](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples) on Github on how to use S3 and other features:

And you should also read their [documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/s3/)